# sonar skipping all modules except root one

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm trying to run sonar on entire project using maven, but for some reason it skips submodules and analyse only root module. Is there any explanation of such a strange behaviour?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is maven final output:

[image: Here is maven final output]

---

### ADDITION

mvn clean install doesn't skip anything, but mvn sonar:sonar do.

---

Comment: Can you post your Pom ? And is there something before the output you added to your question ? Normally, modules are skipped when an error has been encountered before.

Comment: What is the packaging of these submodules?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov, the packaging for all of the modules are "pom"

Comment: @SamuelEUSTACHI, No error is showed, moreover I have ANALYSIS SUCCESSFULL for all the modules.

Comment: I assume that's the reason. `pom` projects should not contain source files and should not be analyzed.

Comment: what if you run mvn clean install sonar:sonar  ?

Comment: @SamuelEUSTACHI, it shows, that everything is succeed. Actually, I just found out, that it actually analyses submodules but keep providing "SKIPPED" as an output..

Comment: The Sonar Maven Plugin is an "aggregator" plugin. It's executed only on the root module. That's the reason why Maven flags sub-modules as SKIPPED.

Comment: @SimonBrandhof Your comment looks like an answer. Any chance of posting it as a question, so that others may see it clearly?

Comment: @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource So, you mean that's the way it behaves. And it means sub-modules are analyzed, but since command was executed at `root` project, `sub-projects` will be skipped. Did I get you right ?

Comment: @soufrk exact. I add an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The SonarQube Maven Plugin is an aggregator plugin. It's executed only on the root module. That's the reason why Maven flags sub-modules as SKIPPED, even if they are correctly analysed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not find full description, but have youtried sonar.includedModules=rootModule?

[Source](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters)