# How to get sonar to analyze nested files?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Every time I run mvn sonar:sonar it only checks the parent file and none of the nested folders.

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] NAV :: XXXAppParent ........................... SUCCESS [ 51.557 s]
[INFO] NAV :: XXXNavAppWeb .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] NAV :: XXX-navapp-web-config ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] NAV :: XXX-navapp-assets-tar ..................... SKIPPED
```

How do I get sonar to get analyze all children files and folders?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sonar skipping all modules except root one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063154/sonar-skipping-all-modules-except-root-one)